# Google Colab Object detection notebook - NameError: name 'object_detection' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I'm trying to run [this notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) on Google colab in cloud. I'm following these [installation instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) linked there but I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong that object_detection is undefined. I do not get any errors while installing libraries or during COCO API installation. How do I import object_detection correctly?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a link to a copy of the colab notebook that you're working on so we can see if there's anything wrong with how you're setting up your colabs environment?

Comment: this has been a nightmare for me as well to say the least.  there is a huge confusion about this subject.  google collab support cannot give a straight answer to this and i think what ever the reason. this problem has been recurring since 5 years ago,  very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your object detection directory is in your drive and you are using the correct path while importing it?